# Returning to product listing page from the detailed product page in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to implement the feature in the Magento that if I go to the product detailed page from the product listing page and if I go back then it should be returned to the same place from where I would have gone to the detailed page. It is returning me to the first product every time if I go back from the detailed product page to the product listing page. 
Example:
If I go to the particular product page from here http://prntscr.com/jjdq0r, and I get http://prntscr.com/jjdqfi product detailed page and if I return from there to the product listing page it should return me at the same place http://prntscr.com/jjdqt7. I am not getting like this on my website now. It's returning me to the first product from the product list every time.
Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This should be simple

1. Get current Category Id from registry

```
$cat_id = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
```

2. Get Category Url from category id

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);
$category_url = $category->getUrl();
```

3. Use this URL in ahref using a button/link on product Page.

Comment: So you can use $category_url variable in ajax request as it is, on the click of a  button/link  like onclick="<?php echo $category_url;?>"

Comment: Thank you answer. 
I have used ajax for the pagination. 
For example: 
Category - saree
If I am at listing of Saree qnd the pagination is done by ajax in it. If I am at 4th product of 3 rd page and I am going to that particular single product page and I go back from there then I am returning to the 1st page rather than 3rd page and I want a solution for that. I hope you can get it.